# python cpu consumption

Tags: python

I wrote a simple python program that looks to me like it should be cpu intensive:

```
for a in range(0,1500):
      for b in range (0,a):
            for c in range(0,b):
                   x = a+b+c
                   print x
```

What happens is that it takes a really long time on solving it, but cpu consumption stays at around 25%. Why does this happens insead of using more cpu for a shorter time?

Comment: What happens if you take `Print x` out?

Comment: @Greg it will still be time-consuming and will still only run on one core.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably running this on a quad-core CPU. Since this code will only run on one core, it will show as taking 25% of the total, when the single core is actually at 100%.

On some operating systems, CPU usage will be shown as 100% per core (so that the total can go above 100%). On those operating systems your code should show 100% CPU usage.

Comment: @miku The GIL's not really relevant here; this isn't multithreaded code.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Checking again I see that Core 1 and Core 3 both go up to about 60%.